# Ajax date picker not showing complete values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have attached an imae of error i have to to use ajax datetime picker but it appears and not shown complete listy of value see image below
  [error image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5nRd.png)

these files i ma using in header for kendo use

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
 <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="js/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="js/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

ajax code is this.

```
     <div>
         <b>From</b>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


             <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" 
                             EnablePageMethods="false"      
               EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceLoanTakenDate" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
    PopupButtonID="txtfrom" TargetControlID="txtfrom" 
    OnClientDateSelectionChanged="ceLoanTakenDate_dateSelectionChanged">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<b>To</b>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/YYYY" PopupButtonID="txtto"
    TargetControlID="txtto">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ceLoanTakenDate_dateSelectionChanged(sender, args) {
        $find("<%= CalendarExtender1.ClientID %>").set_startDate(sender.get_selectedDate());
    }
</script>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a "<" at the beginning of your CSS file declaration:

```
link href="js/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If you fix that does it make a difference?

Comment: not in code this is only while pasting on this site